# Changing a text file from a HTML form

Tags: ajax, text

I'm just wondering if there's any way I can change the data held in my text file by filling out a HTML form on my website.

I've used AJAX to read to the website before but I don't know if its possible the other way round..

Ok so I don't really have any code yet cause I'm not sure how to do it.. but essentially, I want this HTML form:

```
<form name="updateGallery">

        <b>Image:</b> <input type="image" name="image"/><br>

        <b>Name:</b> <input type="text" name="name"/><br>

        <b>Description and Price:</b> <input type="text" name="desPrice"/><br><br>

        <input id="start" type="submit" onclick="submit" value="Update"/>

        <input id="start" type="reset" value="Cancel"/>

    </form>
```

to read to a text file I have set up containing information on items including - the name, an image of the item, description and price.

Comment: show some code what you are talking about.

Comment: Yes - but you need some serverside logic to do that

Comment: I'm really new to all this.. I was wondering if it was possible to do using AJAX the same sort of way I read the data from the text file to a webpage?